# Is there way to increase the value of a HTML table cell (only integers), when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Is there way to increase the value of a HTML table cell (only integers) when a check box is checked, and then remove the addition when it is unchecked?

I would like to use a check box to change the values of a cell, I am using it as a filter on a high chart drawn from an HTML table. So, if the value of the cell changes, and I refresh the chart the user will see a rise in the chart point. Similarly, an unchecked box will decrease the value back to the original number.

I have only found answers about text areas, and when assigning the selector to the td it fails.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What's your representative HTML? Have you made a start, and become stuck somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given HTML along the lines of:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="togglePlusOne" />
                    Add, or remove, 1
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then the following jQuery will allow the addition, or subtraction, of `1` to occur from the text-value (converted to an integer) upon the checking, or unchecking, respectively:

```
$('.togglePlusOne').change(function(){
    var nextCell = $(this).closest('td').next().toggleClass('oneAdded');
    nextCell.text(function(i,t){
        return parseInt(t,10) + ($(this).hasClass('oneAdded') ? 1 : -1);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZydDU/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [Conditional ('ternary') operator (`assessment ? ifTrue : ifFalse;`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 1):

because table cells do not have values, so you can not set the value like you would for textboxes or textareas.

You would be using `.text()` or `.html()` to set the value.

```
var cell = $("#yourSelector");
var currentVal = parseInt(cell.text(), 10);
cell.text( currentVal + 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="togglePlusOne" />Add, or remove, 1 <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="togglePlusOne" />Add, or remove, 1<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="togglePlusOne" />Add, or remove, 1<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="togglePlusOne" />Add, or remove, 1<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="togglePlusOne" />Add, or remove, 1<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="togglePlusOne" />Add, or remove, 1<br>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td id="tsCell">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
   $(function(){
    var $tableCellObj = $("#tsCell");
    $('.togglePlusOne').click(function () {
             var cellValueInt = parseInt($tableCellObj.html());
             cellValueInt = isNaN(cellValueInt) ? 0:cellValueInt;
                  if(this.checked === true)    {
                      $tableCellObj.text(cellValueInt+1)
                  }else{
                      $tableCellObj.text(cellValueInt-1)
                 }
     });
});
</script>
```